# Flutter combine each single element of sublist index

Tags: flutter

[image]Can i ask you some question about flutter list? I have a list ([Red,White,Yellow],[40,41,42],[Small,Big]), and I want to combine to DataTable DataRow DataCell (TextFormField):

Red,40,Small

White,40,Small

Yellow,40,Small

Red,41,Small

White,41,Small

Yellow,41,Small

Red,42,Small

White,42,Small

Yellow,42,Small

Red,40,Big

White,40,Big

Yellow,40,Big

Red,41,Big

White,41,Big

Yellow,41,Big

Red,42,Big

White,42,Big

Yellow,42,Big

Comment: You can use nested for loops to iterate over each list and create the combinations you need. Then, you can use the ```DataTable``` widget to display the data.

Comment: Can you illustrate what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Newbee thanks you so much, but I am really new with flutter nested loops, can you show me some? Thanks you .

Comment: @DhafinRayhan Hi! I want to make the product variants.

Comment: I will post an answer to give you an hint on how to do it. If not useful, please tell me so I will delete it.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/trotter - the docs say: "Class definitions for pseudo-lists that simplify working with structures commonly encountered in combinatorics such as permutations, combinations and subsets."

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how you use nested loop to get every combination of that three categories.

```dart
final colors = ['Red', 'White', 'Yellow'];
final sizes = [40, 41, 42];
final types = ['Small', 'Big'];

final records = <(String, int, String)>[];

for (final color in colors) {
  for (final size in sizes) {
    for (final type in types) {
      records.add((color, size, type));
    }
  }
}

for (final record in records) {
  print(record);
}
```

Output:

```
(Red, 40, Small)
(Red, 40, Big)
(Red, 41, Small)
(Red, 41, Big)
(Red, 42, Small)
(Red, 42, Big)
(White, 40, Small)
(White, 40, Big)
(White, 41, Small)
(White, 41, Big)
(White, 42, Small)
(White, 42, Big)
(Yellow, 40, Small)
(Yellow, 40, Big)
(Yellow, 41, Small)
(Yellow, 41, Big)
(Yellow, 42, Small)
(Yellow, 42, Big)
```

To access the color of the third element, for example, you can do this:

```dart
print(records[2].$1) // prints 'Red'
```

Comment: Really Thanks you! But if your data are dynamic, so how to handle the length?

Comment: Which length are you referring to? If what you mean is that one of the category can have more items (like an additional color 'Purple') then it's automatically handled by the for-in loops. Just try adding 'Purple' to `colors` and see the output.

Comment: For easy to understand from you, I just add an image to my post.

Comment: Yes, of course. You are right, and another case is if we have other variants type that similar to Size, Colors, Types.. etc...

Comment: In that case you might want to use [trotter](https://pub.dev/packages/trotter) package as mentioned by pskink

Answer (score 0):

1. Define your data.

```
List<String> data = [
 'Red,40,Small',
 'White,40,Small',
 'Yellow,40,Small',
 //... add all your data here
];
```

2. Create a function to convert each string into a `DataRow`. Each `DataRow` will contain `DataCell` widgets for each value in the string. In your case, you want to use `TextFormField` widgets in the `DataCell` widgets. This allows the user to edit the values in the table.

```
List<DataRow> _createRows() {
 return data.map((row) {
   var cells = row.split(',');
   return DataRow(cells: [
     DataCell(TextFormField(initialValue: cells[0])),
     DataCell(TextFormField(initialValue: cells[1])),
     DataCell(TextFormField(initialValue: cells[2])),
   ]);
 }).toList();
}
```

3. Create a function to create the columns for the `DataTable`.

```
List<DataColumn> _createColumns() {
 return [
   DataColumn(label: Text('Color')),
   DataColumn(label: Text('Size')),
   DataColumn(label: Text('Category')),
 ];
}
```

4. Finally, create the `DataTable` in the `build` method of your widget.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return DataTable(
   columns: _createColumns(),
   rows: _createRows(),
 );
}
```

This will create a `DataTable` where each row is editable. The user can edit the values in the table using the `TextFormField` widgets.

Comment: For easy to understand from you, I just add an image to my post.